# Does there exist a poset whose "quasiwidth" strictly exceeds its width?

Tags: order-theory

Let $P$ denote a poset. Then the *width* of $P$ is defined as the supremum of the set of all cardinal numbers $\kappa$ such that $P$ has an antichain of cardinality $\kappa$. By the *quasiwidth* of $P$, let us mean the infimum of the set of all cardinal numbers $\kappa$ such that $P$ can be covered by $\kappa$-many chains. It can be shown that:

> **Proposition.** The width of a poset is less than or equal to its quasiwidth.

To see this, use:

> **Proposition.** Consider a fixed poset. Let $A$ denote an antichain therein and $K$ denote a covering by chains. Then there is a surjective partial function $A \leftarrow K$ defined by assigning to each $k \in K$ the unique $a \in A$ such that $a \in k$, whenever such an $a$ exists.
>
> It follows that $|A| \leq |K|$, whenever $A$ is an antichain and $K$ is a covering of the poset by chains.

Anyway, what I'd like to know is:

> **Question.** Does there exist a poset whose quasiwidth strictly exceeds its width?

Comment: There is such an example by M. Perles, look at page 8 [here](http://math.hawaii.edu/~jb/math618/os1uh.pdf).

Comment: @RandomJack, thanks, that is a nice reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [reference](http://math.hawaii.edu/~jb/math618/os1uh.pdf) provided by Random Jack:

- What I'm calling the quasiwidth is usually called the *chain covering number,* denoted $c(P)$.
- The width is denoted $w(P)$.
- Its a general principle that $w(P) \leq c(P)$.
- If $P$ is finite, then $w(P) = c(P)$.
- If $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal, then: $$w(\kappa \times \kappa) = \aleph_0, \qquad c(\kappa \times \kappa) = \kappa$$
- Hence if $\kappa$ is uncountable, then $$w(\kappa \times \kappa) < c(\kappa \times \kappa).$$